Measure text width and height on .NET6+
Is there any possibility to measure a text width and height on .NET6+ cross-platform?
Something like:
var font = new Font("Arial", 16);
var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
var size = gfx.MeasureString("mystring", font);

Goal:

I want to know the text width and height in milimeters
My application should target linux

Actual results:
The TextRenderer.MeasureText function is part of System.Windows.Forms which is limitted to -windows.
Another option is Graphics.MeasureString it is part of System.Drawing which is generally available without much dependencies but this function is also flagged as -windows.

The docs that warn about System.Drawing's cross-platform issues also suggest alternative libraries that are actually better for image processing than System.Drawing itself. Have you tried eg ImageSharp or SkiaSharp?

Sidenote. What you show is not how windows renders text and could be measured. Its about how GDI+ would do it. You could use TextRenderer instead that then would use GDI to render/measure text. But that would be different from what GDI+ does with a different result. So measuring text sizes isn't actually about plattform is about the used rendering engine used on a plattform and you need to measure what that render engine does.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/

Why do you want to measure text? Combining request and cross-platform requirement I suspect it's about UI, namely about layout and there are usually other means to ensure text fits, wraps or do not wraps. Or am I wrong and you are making cross-platform bitmap editor/tool? Or even more specifically linux-only app?

Thanks @panagiotis-kanavos! SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing is providing such a function and is fully cross-platform compatible:
var font = SystemFonts.CreateFont("Arial", 10);
var fontRectangle = TextMeasurer.MeasureAdvance("Foo", new TextOptions(font));

